# How can I change the text color next to a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick question I have 3 checkbox's

I want to make the text next to them white, and by text next to time I mean the YES part

any idea's ?

```html
 <div class="wrapper3">
 <h3 style="color:white;"><i>Choose Your Game Preferences</i></h3>
 <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You Want Sound ?</i></h4>
 <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="sound">Yes
    <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You want Text ?</i></h4>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="text">Yes
 <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You want Flashes ?</i></h4>
    <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="flash">Yes
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a span is easiest:

```
<h4><i>Do You want Flashes ?</i></h4>
   <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="flash">
   <span class="whiteText">Yes</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.whiteText {
color: white;
}
```

Or with inline styling by replacing the class with a `style="color:white;"`.

Comment: You should consider using a label instead.
When using a label, if you specify its for attribute with the id of your form item, clicking on the label will trigger the element as-if your really were clicking on it. Easy to use and user-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can kill two birds with one stone by giving all your checkbxes and radio buttons labels, with a "for" attribute.

This firstly allows you to attach CSS to the label (give the label an id for this). But it is also the correct way to script checkboxes and radios these days, to make your web site accessible to the disabled. People who have impaired eyesight, or impaired handling, have difficulty clicking items as small as checkboxes. A labels becomes selectable along with the checkbox it is attached to, providing a much bigger area for the user to click on. It's good practice these days, especially if you do professional web development.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a label and style the label. I ll use inline styles here but it's best practice to separate html and CSS

```
<div class="wrapper3">
   <h3 style="color:white;"><i>Choose Your Game Preferences</i></h3>
   <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You Want Sound ?</i></h4>
   <label style="color:white;"><input type="checkbox" value="No" id="sound">Yes</label>
   <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You want Text ?</i></h4>
   <label style="color:white;"> <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="text">Yes</label>
   <h4 style="color:white;"><i>Do You want Flashes ?</i></h4>  
   <label style="color:white;"> <input type="checkbox" value="No" id="flash">Yes</label>
</div>
```